# No object exists at the desired reference, Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm new to Firebase, currently using firebase storage and have successfully uploaded my files (problem is not here).

The problem relies in getting the download link of the uploaded files.

Code

```
    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('userImages/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}');

    if(image != null){
      ref = ref.child(Uri.file(image!.path).pathSegments.last);
      var link = await ref.putFile(image!).snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL(); //this line generates error
      // or even link = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      ref = ref.parent!;
    }
    if(cover !=null){
      ref = ref.child(Uri.file(cover!.path).pathSegments.last);
     var link = await ref.putFile(cover!).snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      ref = ref.root;

    }
```

```
E/StorageException(16989): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(16989): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(16989):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(16989): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
E/StorageException(16989): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
```

i think the reference is pointing to something wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
if(image != null){
      ref = ref.child(Uri.file(image!.path).pathSegments.last);
      await ref.putFile(image!);
      print(await ref.getDownloadURL());
      ref = ref.parent!;
    }
```

it works, but there's something we should focus on:

`ref.putFile()`, **this method returns a value but not in the `Future`** what's the purpose of the await here, isn't it unnecessary!.

but it makes the code work, I tried it. it's another question here!